# Unknow output when subtrating result with number

Tags: php

I was trying to subtrat a result output with number am geting unknown result result example `555555` instead of 5 here is my code:

```
<?php
$txt = "12345678910"; 
$nu = 2;
$u = 8;
$disp = str_split($txt, $nu); 
for($i = 0; $i < $u; $i++) {
    $count += count($disp[$i]);
    if(strlen($disp[$i]) != $nu)
    {
        $count = substr($count, 0, 1);
        $uu = ($count - 1);
        $we =substr($uu, 0, 1);
        echo $we;
    }
}  
?>
```

thanks for reading and impact in my solutions

Comment: I just want to get single result example 5  instead of 55555

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in answer to removing your errors so it just displays 5.

I seriously have no understanding as to your intentions with this code but to get rid of your errors, you need to refactor things.

Your value of `$u` is dependant upon the length of `$txt` and how many digits you set in str_split. Your value of $u is too big as the entries for indexes 6 and 7 do not exist in your array.

1st go ...

```
<?php    
$txt = "12345678910"; // The string of digits

$nu = 2;              // How many digits per array
$disp = str_split($txt, $nu); // The array of strings of $nu digits
$u = count($disp); // Calculate the size of $disp - don't guess

$count = 0; // initialise the variable

for ($i = 0; $i < $u; $i++) {
    $count += count($disp[$i]); // count($disp[$i]) will always be 1                         
    // Looking for an entry that isn't $nu digits in size
    if (strlen($disp[$i]) != $nu) {                     
        $count = substr($count, 0, 1); // Rip off the 1st digit of the index count
        $uu = ($count - 1); // decrement it?
        echo $uu; // display it
    }
}
```

Another way...
So using foreach is nicer as it takes care of all the hard work.

```
<?php
$txt = "12345678910";
$nu = 2;

$disp = str_split($txt, $nu);
// DEBUG
var_dump($disp);

$count = 0; // Initialise the variable before we can += it
foreach ($disp as $number) {
    $count += 1;
    if (strlen($number) != $nu) {
        // Taking the index count, getting the 1st digit
        $count = substr($count, 0, 1);
        // Then subtracting 1 from it
        $uu = $count - 1;
        echo $uu;
    }
}
```

So this only addresses what you have so it's a bit nicer and without errors ONLY.

Typecasting blindly on the fly in PHP from strings to integers and back again can be a trap.